# jquery ui sortable, div block in first item not visible

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to make the div - "small_box" in the first item of sortable list to be always not visible. I tried with jquery first() but that works only once and only for one and same element whenever it's dragged. How can i simple make it back to be visible when I dragg it into other than first place and then make invisible "small_box" for the item which jumps in the first place?

I put the live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/kriskasper/3knnn/

```
<ul id="sortable" class='connectedSortable'>
<li>
    <div class="small_box">small box</div>     
    <div class="big_box">big box</div>
</li>        
<li>
    <div class="small_box">small box</div>     
    <div class="big_box">big box</div>
</li>        
<li>
    <div class="small_box">small box</div>     
    <div class="big_box">big box</div>
</li>

<li>
    <div class="small_box">small box</div>     
    <div class="big_box">big box</div>
</li>       
</ul>
```

And here is jquery ui function:

```
    $(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        opacity: 0.6,
        revert: 70

    });
});
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should play with the sortable plugin events. The sortreceive event is fired when the connected element receives an item. My guess would be something like ...

```
$("#sortable").bind("sortreceive", function(event, ui) {
    $(".connectedSortable .small_box").show();
    $("#sortable .small_box").first().hide();
});
```

Comment: I used this:

`$(function() {
 $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        opacity: 0.6,
        revert: 70

});

$("#sortable").bind("sortreceive", function(event, ui) {
$(".connectedSortable .small_box").show();
$("#sortable .small_box").first().hide();
});

});`

But it's not working, I don't know what I'm doing wrong. [ttp://jsfiddle.net/3knnn/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/3knnn/4/)

Comment: You got me all confused with the connectedSortable, which you're not using, since you only have one list. You can solve this with a simple css `ul li:first-child .small_box { display: none; }`

Comment: Check out these two fiddles. one with css, the other with js. http://jsfiddle.net/3knnn/11/ and http://jsfiddle.net/3knnn/14/

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks for help very much! Sorry, I should have clear it from connectedSortable class, it left from the example i'm working on which has two lists.